# How to skip vim message "Press Enter..." after running bash commands

Tags: bash, vim

After running bash commands(e.g `!mv file1 file2`) vim outputs result of that command and prints this message:

*Press Enter or type command to continue*

Is there a way to skip this message and return to vim automatically?

Comment: This has already been discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890802/vim-disable-press-enter-or-type-command-to-continue-prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can disable it, but you could use a mapping and append `<CR>`:

```
map <F4> :!mv file1 file2<CR><CR>
```